# Junction box from main to subpanel - what to do?

Tags: grounding, junction-box, splices

I am doing a DIY 400A service upgrade and I would like to get some vetting on my work before the utility connects it and the city inspects it. The meter/main combo is outside behind this wall of the garage and I have drilled through the wall to install the nipples you see. The wires will go from a breaker in the main panel to a subpanel in the garage. I ran three 1/0 XHHW-2 wires and a 4 AWG XHHW-2 (aluminum) for the ground. The wire supplier apparently did not have bare aluminum conductor.

[image: Junction Box]

Is this lookin good? Of course I need to pull the wires a little more so they fit comfortably inside the box. I am starting to think I need to ground the box. If that is the case, can I just remove a little insulation from the existing ground wire without cutting it and clamp a small copper wire that goes to the box?

Comment: Yes ground the box. Carefully strip a ring around the ground and use a lay in lug. It's a little to bolt to back, so probably best to bolt to bottom of box, Scrape off paint behind the lug. Lay in lug:  https://duckduckgo.com/?q=+Ilsco+GBL-4&t=vivaldi&iax=images&ia=images

Comment: So you're feeding the garage <= 120 amps then?  Since it's 1/0 wire.

Comment: @NoSparksPlease thanks for reading my question and taking the time to comment. May I ask - your seems a complete answer, why write it in a comment?

I am looking up those lugs and I hope to find them. Stripping a ring of insulation out of the wire is going to be annoying but if it is deemed useful I will do it in order to do a good job.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica I guess... "yes"? I am not sure what the real question is however and how it pertains to this box. Are you suggesting it is not big enough for these wires? Can you rephrase? It's a box I got ouf of zoro.com, 12x12x6 inches

Comment: @NoSparksPlease can you tap the box and screw the lug to it rather than scrape paint?

Comment: @AlessioSangalli what make/model is it?  There may be a grounding kit available for your box...

Comment: Yes, there is a grounding threaded hole and the box came with the green screw. The reason I was not sure I needed to ground is that there is no splice or exposed connection in this box.

Comment: (1) I didn't post as answer because I thought there were a couple issues that would render answer incomplete.  (2) If you had multiple ground wires passing through the box unspliced you could just use one (sized for largest breaker) to ground the box or pull a separate wire just to ground the box. (3) The instructions that come with the lugs I have used specify using a 1/4-28 thread to mount, I don't know the thickness of the metal of the box so I'm unclear if two full threads would be engaged per 250.8(A)(5) when using 28 tpi vs. 32 used on existing #10 ground screw.

Comment: (4) I find 314.28 separation of conduit entries a little confusing. Angle pulls require separation 6x the diameter of largest conduit plus the sum of conduits entering the same side, so I think you need 14" separation.

Comment: I used two knock-off holes in the main panel to mount the nipples through the wall you see there.

Comment: I was just sanity-checking to make sure you weren't putting 200A on that, since I had not been privy to the photos you later posted of that setup.  We *just* had someone misread 310.60 to think 1/0 was 210A wire, so I wanted to make sure you were not that person.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica OK so to clarify:
- this is 1/0 aluminum wire
- it is connected to a 125A breaker in the main panel
- it goes to a 125A rated sub-panel in the garage
- in the future, I plan to use the other nipple in this box to route another set of wires to another conduit for a new load center
- should I have used 2/0 wire? It's marginally bigger and now I'm second guessing my work

Comment: @AlessioSangalli Nah I just wanted to double-check.  The 1/0 aluminum is *legally* 120A wire.  Your Load Calculation must stay within 120A. But the Round-Up Rule allows a 125A breaker, since 120A is not a standard breaker size. So your plan is fine.  The confusion was actually mine.

Comment: My calculation for this panel is actually 100A, but I went to 125A breaker because I remember I had to give it a 25% more. Sorry I did the plan in 2022 and I forgot the details, as I do not do this every day.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using metal conduit, that counts as the ground.  Just make sure the conduit nuts are tight enough to bite through the paint on both sides.

Reference:
https://steeltubeinstitute.org/resources/equipment-grounding-using-steel-conduit

Comment: I'm sorry the picture should have been clearer - both the nipples and the conduit going to the subpanel are 2in PVC.

Comment: Can you swap the PVC with EMT?  If not, then you'll need to add a ground wire.  This could be a separate ground that only grounds the box to the main panel's ground bar, or you could loop through like @nosparksplease mentioned.

Comment: It would be a lot of work to replace that and honestly I don't want to as PVC conduit is fine in my jurisdiction. I will just run a scrap piece of wire to ground the box to the other side into the ground bar in the panel.