# Are there any obvious issues in my DIY main panel wiring?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, circuit-breaker, aluminum-wiring

I'm in the process of a DIY 400A service upgrade, I roughly wired up the main panel waiting for the utility to schedule the switchover to the new line.

[image]

For now I have installed a single 125A breaker that I will need to continue have power in the house. The black wires come from a [box on the inside](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/292719/junction-box-from-main-to-subpanel-what-to-do/292733). I have marked the neutral with some random white tape and one of the phases with duct tape.

The copper wires go to the Ufer ground. As I had wire in excess, I ran two. The city inspector already approved the ground connection but hasn't seen the other wires.

Are the wires tidy enough? Should I square them up more? The 125A breaker output has flat-blade screws like if it was designed in the 19th century - I need to properly torque those down.

What I am concerned about is that this main panel will only be used to install few more 125A breakers (plus the second 200A above). There aren't many neutral connections for larger size wire.

Comment: It might be too tidy.  Wires usually do not have such tight bends.

Comment: Are you asking for a review of your work prior to the inspection, or is something not working properly and you're trying to figure you what it is? Also, "Ufer", not "U.F.E.R". It's named after [the guy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ufer_ground) who invented it, not some evil spy organization...

Comment: @crip659 you may be considering the wires that came with the panel (top section). I never touched those.

Comment: @FreeMan the utility will schedule the switchover and I want everything to be ready when that happens. As far as I know this should work, but I am open to consider modifications to make it look more "professional" (or to fix errors of course)

Comment: I tweaked the title a bit to match more what is in the body: It seems you want to know if there are any problems. But the title sounded like someone had said "That's wrong" but didn't tell you what was wrong.

Comment: I would think that "random white tape" and duct tape would be inappropriate for wire marking. You're spending a lot of cash on this heavy up, use some quality electrical tape. The extra buck or two will disappear into the overall project cost.

Comment: The subpanel ground wire overlapping the bus bars looks a bit sloppy.  I'm sure that could be moved easily.

Comment: I can certainly buy some good electrical tape that I will use for several other connections anyway. Is there a list of known, good colors I should use? I'd like to mark the ground too. White for neutral, green for ground, what to use for phases?

Comment: Yes @RobertChapin - now that you point that out it's obvious I should do that (also in order to be able to install the panel cover correctly)

Comment: What gauge is the black wire going to the left bus bar? You mention 125A subpanels, that looks aluminum, so I assume it's a #4 gauge aluminum ground. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes it's #4 and the other wires going to the subpanel are 1/0 (all aluminum)

Comment: White, gray, and green are reserved to neutral and ground so are off-limits for marking phases. Any other recognizable color is fine.

Comment: The black insulation without marking is fine for the hot conductors.

Comment: @crip659 The wires with the 90˚ bends are factory-installed and covered by the panel's listing. There is no issue with those.

Comment: You don't have to mark the phases and there are a whole bunch of common colors but most commonly, red and blue are used in residential, while yellow orange and brown are used for three phase so maybe avoid those.   It's useful to have them marked so that if you have problems down the line you can easily identify both ends of a wire.  The ground from inside obstructing the breaker space is annoying but if this is temporary it doesn't matter more.

Comment: Unless someone already mentioned it: **Where is the service feed neutral?** I see two pairs of hots coming in from the top left to two big breakers at the top. One of those feeds the panel. But I don't see a big neutral from the top going to the panel from the top left.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact There is no reason to expect the service neutral to be a wire. It could be an uninsulated bus bar (i.e. an extension of the bar we see joining the two neutral/ground bars).

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact the neutral comes in from the left side of the panel through the bar where I attached the ground wires to. I have checked :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Three problems for sure:

1. Duct tape is not listed for marking electrical wires. When using tape, you must use UL-listed tape. (The same rule applies to the white tape on the neutral but it looks "close enough" to legitimate electrical tape that an inspector probably wouldn't question it)
2. Gray is not a valid color for marking hot wires. Gray is reserved for neutral, along with white. There isn't actually a requirement to give distinguishing marks to the two hot wires on a 240V split-phase circuit, so you could just remove the duct tape and be fine.
3. The #4 ground wire going inside isn't marked. It needs to be marked green.

Comment: Duct tape has flammable fibers in it for added strength. You can see someone [using duct tape to start a fire](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FnxIvZ4hqK8). Not exactly something you want in a panel.

Comment: Duct tape also has a tendency for the glue to dry up and cease to stick to anything, therefore falling off or sliding to where it's unable to be read.

Comment: I asked my wife what was the white tape she gave me and she said it's the tape used to keep gauze in place when you have a cut. I have placed an order for a set of Super35 in a variety of colours

Answer (score -2):

As @nobody points out, get rid of duct tape, mark your grounding wire green. If you notice, right behind where your wires connect to 125A breaker, there is a large gauge lug, possibly 2. There is also a whole neutral/ground bus on right hand side of panel. I would relocate your neutral and grounding conductors to right side, leaving the space on left clear for the remaining conduits.  The #4 Grounding Electrode Conductors can be terminated in the bus on the right as well. However I believe you stated you installed 2 Ufer's? If so, you will still need at least 1 driven ground rod, 5/8" x 8' minimum. Code requires 2 grounding electrodes, ONE of which must be a driven ground rod. From what I can see, you should have 5 or so lugs still open that will accept at least 1/0, if not, home Depot carries lugs designed to attach to the bus for extra large gauge connections.

Nec 250.52 and 250.53 cover grounding electrode requirements.  A single electrode can only be a rod, pipe, or plate type and to not require a supplemental electrode, must be verified to be maximum 25 ohms to ground. Your concrete encased electrode (ufer) is an acceptable supplemental electrode.

Comment: The two copper wires go to the same Ufer. I forgot the details when I looked it up before, but I thought the Ufer alone is plenty. The city inspector already checked that part, so now I'm a little confused why I would need an additional rod. Do you have the code number so that I can try to look it up?

Comment: "Code requires 2 grounding electrodes, ONE of which must be a driven ground rod."  Where does the code say that?

Comment: @Mark -- the answer's misreading the applicable Code -- it's only water pipes and made rods/pipes/plates that require the supplemental rod.  An Ufer, structural steel-in-soil ground, ground ring, or metal well casing ground is sufficient by itself.  See NEC 250.53(A)(2) and (D)(2) for details

Comment: @AlessioSangalli -- the Ufer is definitely plenty!

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Thank you.  My recollection was that an Ufer ground was considered the ultimate grounding system, so the need for something else didn't make sense.